# How do I find the percentage of people in a group in SAS?

Tags: sas

```
DATA test;
INPUT name$ group_no$;
CARDS;
John 1 
Michelle 1
Peter 1 
Kai 2
Peter 2
Liam 2
Claire 2 
Sam 3
Jim 3
run;
```

How do I find the percentage of people within each group. i.e 33.3% in group 1. 44.4% in group 2 etc....

I tried using the code below but it was not sufficient in answering my question. I believe I may have to use SQL code;

```
Proc FREQ data = test;
TABLE group_no;
BY group_no;
RUN;
```

Please let me know how to solve the issue.

Comment: Maybe it was super sufficient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proc means as shown by data *null* is the way to go. In SQL you can do as shown below.

```
 proc sql;
select group_no, 
  count(group_no) *100/(select count(*) from test) as percentage format= 5.2
from test
group by group_no
 ;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Proc FREQ data = test;
   TABLE group_no;
   RUN;
```

[image]