# How do I obtain the percentage of elements within a group, in a SAS data table?

Tags: sas

I created the following data table;

```
DATA test;
INPUT gender$ group_no$;
CARDS;
Male 1
Female 2
Male 3
Male 2
Female 1
Female 2
Male 1
Female 3
Female 3
Male 2
Male 1
run;
```

I want to find out the gender percentage in each group. I started off with the code below, but I am not to sure where to go from here. Can someone help please?

```
proc sql;
select gender, group_no,
count(gender)
from test
group by gender, group_no
;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the percentage of people in a group in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498180/how-do-i-find-the-percentage-of-people-in-a-group-in-sas)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **`FREQ`** procedure to achieve this.

**Code**

```
proc freq data = test;
tables gender/nocum;
run;
```